# Checking against Undefined in condition in Transpiled code to JS Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was randomly looking on an angular code which was generated after transpiling. Here is how it looked:

```
var __decorate = (undefined && undefined.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
```

Here I am not able to undersatand the way `undefined` is being used. Could somebody please explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably some code block like below:

```
const decorate = (SomeGlobalVariable && SomeGlobalVariable._decorate) || function () {...}
```

Comment: So the `SomeGlobalVariable` resolves to be `undefined` here?

Comment: Yeah; it might be a service which would only be defined in production mode for example. In the end, this should be a service depending on an environment variable (most probably process.env.NODE_ENV). 
Maybe you can try to check production ready code for similar block